# Allow HTTPS traffic for an A-record pointing to a domain with a valid SSL certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, a-record

I use a service for landing pages, with a subdomain like `myname.securedomain.com`. When I access this subdomain with HTTPS, there's a valid SSL certificate. All good.

That service allows me to use a subdomain of my own site (eg, `offer.mysupersite.com`), with an A-Record pointing to the IP address behind `myname.securedomain.com`. It works well with HTTP, but the HTTPS access causes an error `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`. The name for the certificate (`securedomain.com`) is different than my domain name (`mysupersite.com`).

Summary

- `https://myname.securedomain.com` -> ok
- `http://offer.mysupersite.com` -> ok
- `https://offer.mysupersite.com` -> ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

How can I remove this error for HTTPS traffic? I need a way to say it's the same website.

NB: I have the possibility to create TXT records on both sides. Would it help?

Comment: Which service do you use?

Comment: OVH, a French service provider

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a separate ssl certificate for each domain you want to enable ssl for. mysupersite.com and securedomain.com can not have the same SSL certificate only if it's a SAN certificate.

Http works because it does not use SSL/TLS.

Comment: There is such a thing as the [SAN certificate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) extension that allows combining multiple host/domain names in a single certificate. Better to say that the (web) server is configured with a (valid) certificate that includes  your domain. That can be be a separate certificate or part of a certificate that includes your domain as a certificate alternate domain